# Multidimensional Array keeps on returning undefined for 2nd element of 2nd dimension

Tags: javascript

So, I've got the following code.... pretty straight forward...

```
var insTbl = [[' ',' ']];
insTbl.push(['A',sname]);
```

Then, when I loop through it, `insTbl[1][1]` returns `A`, but `insTbl[1][2]` returns `undefined`.

This is driving me insane. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's `sname`? On top of it, `insTbl[1][2]` returns `undefined` because you don't have index `2` in your array.

Comment: array index starts from `0`

Comment: `insTbl[1][1]` is whatever you have in `sname` variable & this is the second element of your second nested array, you dont have `insTbl[1][2]` hence you get `undefined`, indexes start from 0 in array.

Answer (score 0):

`insTbl[1][1]` should return the value in `sname` because arrays start at an index of zero. Thus, by saying `[1][1]` you are getting the 2nd value of the 2nd value.

`insTbl[1][2]` is returning `undefined` because you do not have a third value in the 2nd array.